# Merging two dataframes based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, how do i merge the 'population' of columns df1 into df2 using countyFIPS and County Name as the key?

```
df1:
    countyFIPS  County Name    State       population
0   0     Statewide Unallocated AL         0
1   1001    Autauga County      AL         55869
2   1003    Baldwin County      AL         223234
3   1005    Barbour County      AL         24686


df2:
countyFIPS  County Name        State    StateFIPS   Date    death   confirm
0   0   Statewide Unallocated   AL        1       2020-01-22    0   0
1   1001    Autauga County      AL        1       2020-01-22    0   0
2   1003    Baldwin County      AL        1       2020-01-22    0   0
3   1005    Barbour County      AL        1       2020-01-22    0   0

idealdf:
countyFIPS  County Name        State    StateFIPS   Date    death   confirm population
0   0   Statewide Unallocated   AL        1       2020-01-22    0   0         0
1   1001    Autauga County      AL        1       2020-01-22    0   0         55869
2   1003    Baldwin County      AL        1       2020-01-22    0   0         223234
3   1005    Barbour County      AL        1       2020-01-22    0   0         223234
```

Comment: i tried inner join but got some nan values

Comment: wait actually nvm i figured it out thanks !